# CSS Tab Menu Keep Rounded Corners when tab is closed

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have this tab menu using jQuery and it all works, however I want to keep the rounded corners on the tab title when the content div is closed, however from this image when the other tabs are closed the tab heading is still left with bottom left and right stright edges:
[image]

As you can see the closed tabs still have the stright edges at the bottom. Is there a way is CSS where I can set the rounded corners to come back when the tab is closed?

Here is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $( "#myaccountSettings" ).accordion(
  {
    heightStyle: "content"
  });

});
```

```css
#myaccountSettings h3
{
  color: #a2a2a2;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  outline: none;
}

#myaccountSettings h3:hover
{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #C33917;
}

#myaccountSettings h3:not(:first-child)
{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.accountTabContentWrapper
{
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #676464;
  border-radius:  0 0 4px 4px;
  color: #d6cbc9;
}

.accountTabContentWrapper h1
{
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="myaccountSettings">

  <h3>General</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

    <h1>Hello, @username</h1>

    

  </div>

  <h3>Email & Password</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

  </div>

  <h3>Delete My Account</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

  </div>

  <!--<h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

  </div>-->

</div>
```

Comment: instead of `#myaccountSettings h3 { border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }` just use `border-radius: 4px`? is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myaccountSettings").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
  });
  $(".headers").click(function() {
    current_head = this;
    //$(current_head).css("border-radius","0px");
    $(current_head).css("border-top-left-radius", "5px");
    $(current_head).css("border-top-right-radius", "5px");
    $(current_head).css("border-bottom-right-radius", "0px");
    $(current_head).css("border-bottom-left-radius", "0px");
    //$(current_head).css("border-top-right-radius","0px");
    $(".headers").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-state-active") && this != current_head) {
        $(this).css("border-radius", "10px");
        console.log(this.innerHTML)
      }
    })

  })
  //trigger a click on first header when window onload to initiate the styling
 $(".headers")[0].click()
});
```

```css
#myaccountSettings h3 {
  color: #a2a2a2;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  outline: none;
}

#myaccountSettings h3:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #C33917;
}

#myaccountSettings h3:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.accountTabContentWrapper {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #676464;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  color: #d6cbc9;
}

.accountTabContentWrapper h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="myaccountSettings">

  <h3 class="headers">General</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

    <h1>Hello, @username</h1>



  </div>

  <h3 class="headers">Email & Password</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

  </div>

  <h3 class="headers">Delete My Account</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

  </div>

  <!--<h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div class="accountTabContentWrapper">

  </div>-->

</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to keep this pure CSS, so in the end I just used top: -2px; and set the position to relative on .accountTabContentWrapper. But your answer does work as well, so that is why I accepted it. Cheers.